# how to type in an excel cell value into search box on a page?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, openpyxl

I am a newbie in programming in general and am challenged with my first script on python. Here is what my script has to do:

1) Loop through the given excel list in a column (via openpyxl)

2) Enter these individual values from the step 1 above into search box of a particular page (via selenium)

3) scrape specific value from the web page and copy these into excel (Beautifulsoup and openpyxl)

I am currently struggling with the second step. Maybe it is very silly of me but I though I assign my excel value to the searchbox and hit the search button but this does not seem to work:

```
search_box = driver.find_element_by_id("searchText") 
search_box = xlsx_list["A2"].value
```

Many thanks in advance for ideas!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any of the two assignments to `search_box`, just use `send_keys`:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("searchText").send_keys(str(xlsx_list["A2"].value))
```